# Drop columns if exist in Dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to drop columns if they are exist in a DataFrame.

Code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alice", 2), ("Bob", 5)], ("name", "age"))
drop_cols=["id","age"]
df.drop(*[drop_cols])
```

> df.drop(*[drop_cols])

How to use condition while dropping column?

I don't want to use

```
if 'column_name' in df.columns:
    df = df.drop('column_name')
```